# Mapbox how set fill colour on MGLPolygonFeature (or add feature attributes)

Tags: swift, mapbox-ios

MGLPolygonFeature is supposed to support MGLFeature as a series of attributes on the PolygonFeature.

However, I can find no documentation on how to go about setting attribute features at a polygon level.  Most documentation refers to tile layer, or I am just missing the glue piece I need to solve this issue.

My goal is to assign a fill, opacity, stroke colour, and stroke width to a polygon at the time I create the polygon feature, so that when I create a multitude of polygons, they all have independent fill colours based on some criteria specific to that particular polygon.

Some attempted code to solve the issue is provided below - but as can be seen, something is missing in order to set the attributes.

```
    let polygon = MGLPolygonFeature(coordinates: coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
    let identifier = "\(name)"
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: identifier, shape: polygon)
    let fill = MGLFillStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)
    fill.fillColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.green)
    fill.fillOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0.3)
    polygon.attribute(forKey: "fillColor") = fill // non-mutable property cannot be added
    return polygon
```

The polygon itself does not have layer properties, but the documentation from mapbox seems to suggest that adding attributes is the way to achieve what I want.

Any clues to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following methods to solve the addition of colors to polygons.

```
func createSourceAndLayer(identifier: String, shapes: [MGLShape]) -> (MGLSource, MGLStyleLayer) {
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: identifier, shapes: shapes)
    let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)
    layer.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white)
    layer.lineWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 2)
    
    return (source, layer)
}

func createFillLayer(identifier: String, source: MGLSource) -> MGLStyleLayer {
    let fillLayer = MGLFillStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)
    fillLayer.fillColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.red)
    fillLayer.fillOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0.25)
    return fillLayer
}
```

Called and configured similar to the below.

```
    let (source, layer) = createSourceAndLayer(identifier: "sourceId", shapes: polygons)
    let fillLayer = createFillLayer(identifier: "fillId", source: source)
    style.addSource(source)

    // Layer is inserted at position count-1 which works for now but we don't really
    // control the z-index of the annotations (cows)
    style.insertLayer(layer, at: UInt(style.layers.count - 1))
    style.insertLayer(fillLayer, at: UInt(style.layers.count - 2))
```